# how to retrieve data exactly from database, including the line spaces and enters?

Tags: php, html, css, sql

i have a php file which retrieves data from my SQL database and its working very fine.. but its not showing with the same structure.. it just dumps everything ass one paragraph.. may i know how to retrieve it exactly with all the spaces and enters..?

Php

```
    <div class="maindiv">
    <div class="divA">
    <div class="title">

    </div>
     <div class="divB">
     <div class="divD">
      <p>Click On Menu</p>
         <?php
         $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");  
          $db = mysql_select_db("SBI", $connection); 

             $query = mysql_query("select * from recipes", $connection);
             while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
               echo  "<b><a href=\"CookWhatLahSBIAfter.php?id=  {$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</a></b>";

          }
                ?>
          </div>
            <?php
              if  (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

          $query1 = mysql_query("select * from recipes where id=$id", $connection);

       while (  $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1))  {
       ?>
      <div class="form">

          <h2>---You can cook..---</h2>

            <h1><span title="Recipe Name" style ="color: #0c0f44; font-size:  15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Name:</span><?php echo $row1['recipename']; ?><br><br></h1>
        <span title="Recipe Ingredients" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Ingredients:</span> <?php echo  $row1['ingredients']; ?><br><br>
        <span title="Recipe Steps" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Recipe:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipe']; ?><br><br><br>

          <h1><span title="Recipe Name" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Name:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipename1']; ?><br><br></h1>
         <span title="Recipe Ingredients"  style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Ingredients:</span> <?php echo $row1['ingredients1']; ?><br><br>
         <span title="Recipe Steps" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Recipe:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipe1']; ?><br><br><br>

         <h1> <span title="Recipe Name" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Name:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipename2']; ?><br><br></h1>
       <span title="Recipe Ingredients"  style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Ingredients:</span> <?php echo $row1['ingredients2']; ?><br><br>
       <span title="Recipe Steps" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Recipe:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipe2']; ?><br><br><br>

       <h1><span  title="Recipe Name" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Name:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipename3']; ?><br><br></h1>
         <span title="Recipe Ingredients"  style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Ingredients:</span> <?php echo $row1['ingredients3']; ?><br><br>
        <span title="Recipe Steps" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Recipe:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipe3']; ?><br><br>

        <h1><span title="Recipe Name" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Name:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipename4']; ?><br><br></h1>
        <span title="Recipe Ingredients"  style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Ingredients:</span> <?php echo $row1['ingredients4']; ?><br><br>
         <span title="Recipe Steps" style="color: #0c0f44; font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:underline;">Recipe:</span> <?php echo $row1['recipe4']; ?><br><br><br>


    </div>
   <?php
      }
     }
      ?>

     </div>

      </div>
      </div>
       <?php
     mysql_close($connection);  
      ?>
```

[this is how my MySql looks like..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQF3o.jpg)
[and this is how it looks in website..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN6AC.jpg)

Comment: please stop marking it as unclear.. i already did my research and asked this..

Comment: Your description of the problem is too vague, no idea what you are talking about. Describe what it is doing, in detail, and what you expect it too. Also, only include relevant code.

Comment: @EvanCarslake hi am actually trying to make a website.. where when the user click the ingredient .. it should be able to show the recipes he can make with it.. its working fine.. but the only problem is.. it junks up everything as one paragraph.. i want it to be like i wrote in database.. each ingredient and cooking steps with its own line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting the data correctly, but the problem is the data in the database itself. I'll explain, for HTML an "enter" means nothing, but `<br/>` means something.

So what you have to do is to save the data in the database WITH HTML tags for the format you want,  instead of "enters" you need `<br/>`, instead of "bold" you need `<b>`, instead of "space" you need `&nbsp` and so on...

The easiest way to do this is to use a WYSIWYG ( What you see is what you get ) editor plugin to save the information. A good one is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). Go see their [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo).  Change some texts and stuff and then click on the "HTML Source" button and it will show you what you should have in your database instead of "plain text"

Answer (score 0):

i believe which ever field you want to display with enters it is

```
<?php echo nl2br($row1['recipe4']); ?>
```

Comment: hi thank you for the reply.. but thats not exactly what am searching for.. i want .. each ingredient to be in their own line.. and the cooking steps also..  how do i do that.. ?